# 18.04.1 - Issues with Firefox and some Applications

Tags: firefox

Today i installed some updates suggested from the OS (Ubuntu 18.04) and youtube videos and some applications have weird behavior, I mean, youtube videos now have a little freezes and the music cut some  seconds of the song and then it continues.

My computer specs are:
AMD A12 9700P
16 GB RAM
SSD 120 GB - Adata Ultimate SU650 (totally new).

I did a new clean installation and each minute it seems like it is running something on background and I have this little freezes/cuts, i can't watch a movie or listen music without interruptions.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 as external hard drive (SSD), it is connected via 3.0

I didn't have this issue my first time, i don't know what is happening now.

I will be grateful if someone gives me recommendations.

Regards!

Comment: Is your internet speed ok?

Comment: Hi. yes it is ok!